# Displaying available stylesheets

Tags: javascript

I want to make an javascript file (attached to some website), which generates available stylesheets and while clicked on one's name changes the current stylesheet for the chosen one.  I do it like that:

```
for(var i=0;i<document.getElementsByTagName("link").length;i++)
{
    var style = document.getElementsByTagName("link").item(i).href   //getting name
    //and here is my problem - I'd like to change that HTML code to js code, so that it                  generates a link wchich should change the style. I can't figure it out how to change that to js.
    <a href="#" onclick="changeCSS(style, 0);">STYLE 3</a>
}
```

//Here is the function that changes stylesheet (not mine, but working)

```
function changeCSS(cssFile, cssLinkIndex) 

{

var oldlink = document.getElementsByTagName("link").item(cssLinkIndex);

var newlink = document.createElement("link")
newlink.setAttribute("rel", "stylesheet");
newlink.setAttribute("type", "text/css");
newlink.setAttribute("href", cssFile);

document.getElementsByTagName("head").item(0).replaceChild(newlink, oldlink);
}
```

Can you please verify my code and help me with changing HTML code with link, to js code?

//Edit

I'm sorry but it's still not working... The website on wchich i'm using the code has 3 stylesheet, but i get no result.

```
for(var i=0;i<document.getElementsByTagName("link").length;i++)
{
  var style = new String(document.getElementsByTagName("link").item(i).href));
  var a = document.createElement("a"); //create an anchor
  a.textContent = a.innerText = "Style "+i; // Set its text to Style+i
  a.onclick = function(){ changeCSS(style,0)}; // When you click it, you call changeCSS 
  document.body.appendChild(a); // Append it to the body
}
```

I used your code, like above.

Comment: Were you able to resolve the issue? Did my answer help?

Answer (score 1):

Inside your loop:

```
var a = document.createElement("a"); //create an anchor
a.textContent = a.innerText = "Style "+i; // Set its text to Style+i
 // When you click it, you call changeCSS 
a.onclick = function(){ changeCSS(style,0)};
document.body.appendChild(a); // Append it to the body
```

If you want to append it to another element, change

```
document.body.appendChild(a);
```

To

```
whatEverElement.appendChild(a);
```

Some remarks:

- [`appendChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.appendChild) adds an element as a child of another element, just like in `changeCSS`
- I set both `textContent` and `innerText` to support old IE, if you don't need to, change to the [`textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.textContent) alone.
- This code is assumed to be in the for loop.
- Depending on what style is, there might be a *closure trap* here, if you see a problem with all elements getting the same style, that's what you got, and you need to wrap the code in another IIFE.

#### [Here is a working example](http://jsfiddle.net/aspbd/)

Note it doesn't use change CSS, but alert because I don't know how to load external sheets in JSFiddle.

Comment: Changed my code, but it still doesn't work. Edited first post to show the entire loop.

Comment: @user2443194 Why are you using a string constructor o_0? When you do `new String` you're creating an _object_ that wraps a string. (Think Integer and int boxing if you know Java)

Comment: Probably something along the lines of : First query `var links = document.getElementsByTagName("link")` (save it in a variable). Then access all the stylesheet links with `links[i].href`.